# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotib'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, pip, modulenotfounderror

I have downloaded the matplotlib module using  `pip install matplotlib`  but got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/good pc/Documents/Jarvis/Machine_learning_model.py", line 3, in <module>
    import matplotib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotib'
```

I have written this code if required

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotib.pyplot as plt 

a = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")

pd.head()
```

I dont know why i am getting this error , because matplotlib is already downloaded in my vscode.

*python version 3.7.3*

**thanks in advance!!!**

Comment: Its a typo.....you are missing `l` in `matplotib` as its name is `matplotlib` so write `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

a = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")

""" The pandas module has no function pd.head().
You can only call .head() on e.g.
a DataFrame of pandas so in this case you need to use a.head()"""

#pd.head()
```

Comment: `AttributeError: module "pandas" has no attribute "head"`

Comment: The pandas module has no function pd.head() which the question asker uses. You can only call .head() on e.g. a DataFrame of pandas so in this case you need to use a.head()

Comment: yep, I tried to answer the question error affected by typo, btw thanks for the correction in pandas methods, you correct next level error :)) .